# In what circumstances will edebug produce different behaviour?

Tags: edebug

I'm trying to debug [this julia-mode indentation issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/8538) using edebug.

The elisp I'm running is [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/contrib/julia-mode.el) and the bug only occurs on Emacs 23.3.

<kbd>TAB</kbd> is bound to `julia-latexsub-or-indent`. I can reproduce the issue. However, if I run `edebug-defun` on `julia-latexsub-or-indent`, the problem disappears!

I know Emacs has a lot of internal state, so I presume some of it is modified by edebug (even though it uses a recursive editor).

When is `edebug` not appropriate for debugging?

Comment: I don't have an answer wrt edebug. But using a debugger sometimes does interfere with reproducing a bug, especially if the bug involves display, timers, window/frame selection etc. You can try using the standard debugger (`debug`) instead: `M-x debug-on-entry RET julia-latexsub-or-indent RET`, but you might hit the same problem. You can also try adding calls to `message` at different places in the source code, to print relevant info to buffer `*Messages*`.